# How do I translate a custom string in "Global: Custom text"?

Tags: 8, views, i18n-l10n

In D9 website I have a view with Global: Custom text field. In that field I have placed a string like this:

```
<span class="general-info">{{ 'General Info:'|t }}</span>
```

I want to add a translation for the string 'General Info' in different languages. So I went to this translation interface (en/admin/config/regional/translate), where I searched for the string but I could not get the result. Is there any way to refresh the list of "source string" ? I have also cleared the cache and run the cron, but after clicking filter, it displayed "No strings available."

Am I missing something ?

[image: Translate Interface]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward way would be to translate the field in *Configuration Translation*. Create a translation of your View and then drill down to the field and translate the rewrite result text of the custom text field.

But your approach, using the *User Interface Translation* system inside of Twig, should work as well. The trick is, once you have implemented the |t filter in the Twig template, you have to visit the page in one of the installed non-English languages. Then you should be able to find the string in the user interface translation UI.